# ¿Con C# se puede saber cuando pulsas el botón de una bandeja del lector?

Tags: c#

Tengo un grabador de DVD que si pulso su botón abre y cierra la bandeja.

He hecho dos cosas. Un formulario Windows con C# que abre y cierra la bandeja del disco y que detecta cuando hay un disco en su interior o no.

El problema está cuando abro y cierro la bandeja directamente del botón físico de la unidad. Visual C# no detecta cuando esto ocurre. Si controlas la bandeja de disco desde C#, si funciona de maravilla.

Dejo un ejemplo del Windwos Form con .Net 5.0.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código C#:

```
    using System;
using System.Management; // No olvidar y añadir en Dependencias, NuGet.
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lector_discos_Net_5_01_cs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Variable.
        public static string datos = "";
        public static string datosId = "";

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, 
            StringBuilder lpstrReturnString,
            int uReturnLength, 
            IntPtr hwndCallback);

        StringBuilder rt = new StringBuilder(127); 

        private void button_Abrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label_Mensaje.Text = "Abriendo...";
            Application.DoEvents();
            mciSendString("set CDAudio!" + comboBox_Unidad.Text + " door open", rt, 127, IntPtr.Zero);

            /* 
               Si quieres por ejemplo elegir la unidad que quieras, en este caso la H, se le asigana !H
               como indica abajo. En vez de CDAudio, CDAudio!H.
               mciSendString("set CDAudio!H door open", rt, 127, IntPtr.Zero);
            */

            label_Mensaje.Text = "Abierto.";
            discoSiNo();
        }

        private void button_Cerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label_Mensaje.Text = "Cerrando...";
            Application.DoEvents();
            mciSendString("set CDAudio door closed", rt, 127, IntPtr.Zero);
            label_Mensaje.Text = "Cerrado.";
            discoSiNo();
        }

        // Lectura de dispositivos.
        void ConsigueComponentes(string hwclass, string syntax)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
            foreach (ManagementObject mj in mos.Get())
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]) != "")
                {
                    datos = Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Comprobar si hay disco en el lector.
        void discoSiNo()
        {
            // Disco en la unidad del lector.
            ConsigueComponentes("Win32_CDROMDrive", "MediaLoaded");

            // ¿Disco en el lector?
            if (datos == "True")
            {
                label_Mensaje_disco.Text = "Disco en el lector: Sí.";
            }

            else
            {
                label_Mensaje_disco.Text = "Disco en el lector: No.";
            }
            datos = "";
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                // Nombre de la unidad.
                ConsigueComponentes("Win32_CDROMDrive", "Id");

                if (datos == "F:")
                {
                    comboBox_Unidad.Text = datos;
                    comboBox_Unidad.Items.Add(datos);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Que tengan buen día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo general veo que esto se trabaja con las clases WMI, prueba la siguiente solución que no usa WMI, creo que podría funcionarte:

```
internal class DriveWatcher
{
    public delegate void OpticalDiskArrivedEventHandler(Object sender, OpticalDiskArrivedEventArgs e);

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtiene o establece el tiempo, en segundos, antes de que el observador de la unidad compruebe la inserción de nuevos medios en relación con la última aparición de la comprobación.
    /// </summary>
    public int Interval = 1;

    private Timer _driveTimer;

    private Dictionary<string, bool> _drives;

    private bool _haveDisk;

    /// <summary>
    /// Ocurre cuando se inserta o expulsa un nuevo disco óptico.
    /// </summary>
    public event OpticalDiskArrivedEventHandler OpticalDiskArrived;

    private void OnOpticalDiskArrived(OpticalDiskArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpticalDiskArrivedEventHandler handler = OpticalDiskArrived;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _drives = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        foreach (
            DriveInfo drive in
                DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(driveInfo => driveInfo.DriveType.Equals(DriveType.CDRom)))
        {
            _drives.Add(drive.Name, drive.IsReady);
        }
        _driveTimer = new Timer {Interval = Interval*1000};
        _driveTimer.Elapsed += DriveTimerOnElapsed;
        _driveTimer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_driveTimer != null)
        {
            _driveTimer.Stop();
            _driveTimer.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void DriveTimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
    {
        if (!_haveDisk)
        {
            try
            {
                _haveDisk = true;
                foreach (DriveInfo drive in from drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                                            where drive.DriveType.Equals(DriveType.CDRom)
                                            where _drives.ContainsKey(drive.Name)
                                            where !_drives[drive.Name].Equals(drive.IsReady)
                                            select drive)
                {
                    _drives[drive.Name] = drive.IsReady;
                    OnOpticalDiskArrived(new OpticalDiskArrivedEventArgs {Drive = drive});
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.Write(exception.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                _haveDisk = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class OpticalDiskArrivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DriveInfo Drive;
}
```

Puede usar esto de la siguiente manera.

```
var driveWatcher = new DriveWatcher();
driveWatcher.OpticalDiskArrived += DriveWatcherOnOpticalDiskArrived;
driveWatcher.Start();

private void DriveWatcherOnOpticalDiskArrived(object sender, OpticalDiskArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Drive.Name);
    //...
    ///Aquí habilitas o desabilitas tu botón según sea necesario...
}
```

---

Con respecto al tema WMI puedes también probar lo siguiente:

```
foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                               .Where(d => d.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom))  
MessageBox.Show(drive.Name + " " + drive.IsReady.ToString());
```

Para más información, consultar estas preguntas:

[Detecting if disc is in DVD drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11420421/8933039)

[Use WMI to detect if disk in CD/DVD drive](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ecb74cd-d193-40f5-9aa3-47a3c9adb4ea/use-wmi-to-detect-if-disk-in-cddvd-drive?forum=csharpgeneral)